# How can I change a button style dynamically in Android?

Tags: android, button, coding-style

I want to change the style of a button dynamically, i.e. in Java code, something like:

```
((Button)findViewById(id)).setStyle("@styles/foo")

<resources>
    <style name="foo">
        <item name="android:adjustViewBounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">100px</item>
        <item name="android:maxWidth">200px</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I have not seen nothing like setStyle, so:

do I have to change every single property or I can change the whole style?

Answer (score 24):

To assign a style like this

```
<style name="ButtonHOLO" parent="android:Widget.Button">
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_default_holo_dark</item>
      <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/calc_btn_h</item>
      <item name="android:minWidth">@dimen/calc_btn_w</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

to a button dynamically you need to use both setBackgroundResource() and setTextAppearance() functions. E.g.:

```
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_default_holo_dark);
btn.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.ButtonHOLO);
```

where

> btn_default_holo_dark

is a name of .xml  file which describes a selector for your button.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I found to circumvent this obvious flaw was to make two buttons. Make one of them `Visibility.gone`. Then simply change `Visibility` from the other one to `gone` and activate the first one by `Visibility.visible`.

I don't really like that solution, but it's faster and saner than the alternatives I found so far.